# How do I format the output decimal to two places after the decimal in java?

Tags: java, format, printf

I want my fallingTime numbers to be limited to two decimal places. I used "String.format(%.2f)" but it is giving me an error message.

This is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4426)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2951)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2898)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2673)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2609)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:3302)
        at fallingDistance.main(fallingDistance.java:22)
```

```java
public class fallingDistance {


    public static double fallDistance(int fallingTime){

        double distance;
        double g = 9.8;
        distance = (0.5*g*Math.pow(fallingTime, fallingTime));
        return distance;
    

    }

    //public static void displayHeader(){
        //System.out.println("Time\t\t\t\t\tDistance\n----\t\t\t\t\t--------");
    //}
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        //displayHeader();
        
        for(int time = 1; time <= 10; time++){
            System.out.println(time+ " seconds\t\t" + String.format("%.2f", fallDistance(time) + " meters"));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had misplaced a bracket. The below should work.

```
for (int time = 1; time <= 10; time++) {
    System.out.println(time + " seconds\t\t" + String.format("%.2f", fallDistance(time)) + " meters");

}
```

Comment: This also worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `+` with `,`

```
System.out.println(time + " seconds\t\t" + String.format("%.2f", fallDistance(time), " meters"));
```

Comment: `" meters"` should be either included into format or the format string is missing `%s` placeholder to print `" meters"` prefix

Answer (score 1):

I removed " meters" from the end of the code and put it after "%.2f" and that worked. The code looks like this now:

{System.out.println(time + " seconds\t\t" + String.format("%.2f meters", fallDistance(time)));}